# MySQL stored procedure - How to Return Nothing

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure SP1 that calls another stored procedure SP2 like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1()
BEGIN
    CALL SP2();
END
```

The SP2 stored proc returns a row from a table, but I don't want SP1 to return anything. I tried declaring a dummy variable and ending SP1() with something like "SELECT 0 INTO dummy", but nothing seems to work...

Is there simple way to make SP1 not return the row from SP2?

Comment: Pass parameter to SP2, for example `exec_select`, check it and execute SELECT statement when `exec_select` is true.

Comment: Stored Procedures in MySQL are called routines. You should change that in your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of a stored procedure is `Int` and cannot be changed to return `NULL`.
This looks like [The X Y Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).
Why are you calling `SP2` from `SP1` ? Maybe you could change your design if the return value is causing trouble.

Comment: I agree what I'm trying to do is a bit of hack... Just trying to crank something out quickly for some legacy code that I cannot redesign.

Comment: I too thought that stored procs returned INT, but when I execute one that "returns nothing" from my GUI front end (SQLyog), I get the message displayed "0 row(s) affected" and nothing else returned. Why don't I see an INT?

Comment: Well you pretty much answered yourself there. The INT is the number of affected rows. In your case you don't have any affected rows. 

Int affectedRows = 0;